# Load content (image, title etc.) from URL of Website

Tags: android, json, android-webview

Suppose I have a URL like [this](http://www.thedailystar.net/world/prospects-putin-trump-meeting-apec-summit-unclear-1489216). Now I am trying to show the content of the URL on my app at a glance. Like the below image: [image]

Then what way should I follow. Please help me.

Comment: First thing would be to get the contents of the html page (maybe even download it if you wanted to), then pass it through a reader or custom reader to find and identify where the Images, Title of page, and paragraphs are located, store those found values. Download the image into an image view and set the text based on the values you got from the html page. Probably not the best way, but it will do :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the content from Web URL. Then you have to parse your desired values from the loaded page source.

So, the steps are basically:
 1. Load Html from Web URL
 2. Parse your values from html

Now the step to load the html from web URL.

```
static String  TAG = "WebRequest";
void getWebAsync(String urlString) {
    AsyncHttpClient androidClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

    androidClient.get(urlString, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "responseString: " + responseString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseToken) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Client token: " + responseToken);
            handleHtml(responseToken);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you have to handle the received html source.

```
void handleHtml(String htmlCode) {
    WebModel webModel = extractAllText(htmlCode);

    Log.e("PARSED_MODEL", "Model: " + webModel.toString());

    if (webModel.getTilte() != null) {
        titleTV.setText(webModel.getTilte());
    }

    if (webModel.getMainIamgeURL() != null) {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(webModel.getMainIamgeURL())
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(imageView);

    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}

public WebModel extractAllText(String htmlText){
    Source source = new Source(htmlText);
    String strData = "";

    WebModel webModel = new WebModel();

    List<Element> elements;
    elements = source.getAllElements("title");

    String title = elements.get(0).getContent().toString();
    webModel.setTilte(title);

    elements = source.getAllElements("meta");
    for(Element element : elements )
    {
        final String id = element.getAttributeValue("property"); // Get Attribute 'id'
        if( id != null && id.equals("og:image")){
            strData = element.getAttributeValue("content");
            webModel.setMainIamgeURL(strData);
            break;
        }
    }
    return webModel;
}

public class WebModel {
    String tilte;
    String mainIamgeURL;

    public String getTilte() {
        return tilte;
    }

    public String getMainIamgeURL() {
        return mainIamgeURL;
    }

    public void setTilte(String tilte) {
        this.tilte = tilte;
    }

    public void setMainIamgeURL(String mainIamgeURL) {
        this.mainIamgeURL = mainIamgeURL;
    }
}
```

Here two libraries has been used:
1. [jericho-html-3.4.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.htmlparser.jericho/jericho-html/3.4)
2. [com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)

Finally your result will be look like: [image]